# How to configure Flutter apps to share Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have 2 Flutter applications -- let's call them A and B.
Each application uses *Firebase Authentication* and *Firebase Analytics* (and maybe more Firebase services in the future).
Both applications need to access a shared *Cloud Firestore*, and that access obviously needs to be secure.

*So how can I best do this?*

I have created 3 Firebase Projects:

1. Project A for Flutter application A -- enabled Auth and Analytics
2. Project B for Flutter application B -- enabled Auth and Analytics
3. Project C for Cloud Firestore

For the two Flutter applications, I have downloaded the respective `GoogleService-Info.plist` files and placed them in the project's `ios/Runner` directory.  Each application can successfully login and capture analytics events, and I can clearly segregate activity between the two applications.

Now, I need to point both A and B to C.  I first thought that I could simply update the `DATABASE_URL` in both `GoogleService-Info.plist` files, but that doesn't seem to work.

I have read the [Configure multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)
 documentation, and I can imagine having a secondary `GoogleService-Info.plist` file for the Cloud Firestore, perhaps named `GoogleService-Info-DB.plist`, but then how does one get [FirebaseApp](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseApp-class.html) to load the secondary configuration?  (Note that iOS needs to load the secondary `plist`, and Android needs to load a secondary `json` file.) I only see a [configure](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseApp/configure.html) method that accepts a [FirebaseOptions](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseOptions-class.html) class.

Related, I need to secure Project C's database to only authenticated users from Project A or Project B.  How can I do that?

Comment: Go to your firebase project and in the settings add your projects download 1 config file for each

Comment: I mentioned that I already have `GoogleService-Info.plist` files for A and B.  The challenge is to configure A and B to access C's _Cloud Firestore_ **securely**.

Comment: @AWhitford Yes, possible if these all projects using same firebase account Because in your all this projects bundle id are mention in your google-services.json file. which are you added in your Projects A,B and C.